# Pandas dataframe add new column and updated based on dictionary keys using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to create a new column in a pd df.  I have a dictionary with a tuple of keys as input, that i want to check against a column, and then create a new one with the value from dict.

```
{('Y','y','yes','yeah','YES','Yeah'):'Yes',('N','n','no','nah','NO','NAH','No Data'):'No'}
```

I have this code working, but bcz i'm using the for loop, on the 2nd iteration, it overwrites the new col with the clone_col value, so i basically revert the first iterations changes.  There must be a better with .apply, or .map and lambda functions but i'm not sure.  i've tried apply and a lambda but can't get it to work.  Thanks for any help.

```
for k, v in ast.literal_eval(sources).items():                        
    df_update[column_name] = np.where(
        df_update[clone_col].isin(k),
        v,
        df_update[clone_col],
    )
```

apply attempt:

```
for k, v in ast.literal_eval(sources).items():                        
    df_update[column_name] = df_update.apply(lambda x: v if x[clone_col] in k else x[clone_col], axis=1)
```

this does the same thing as the loop above w/ np.where

For the df results, so if each row has the following:

```
n
Y
N
y
```

I end up getting this, bcz on the iteration for "No", it overwrites the "Yes" records:

```
No
Y
No
y
```

Comment: `df_update['col_name'] = df_update['col_name'].replace(pd.Series({u:v for k,v in d.items() for u in k}))`

Comment: `where` is a numpy function, working with arrays or pandas series. Dictionary is a python structure without any special functionality in numpy or `where`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us flatten the dictionary to create a replacement dictionary of key value pairs then use the `replace` method on the desired column to substitute the values.

```
dct = {('Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yeah', 'YES', 'Yeah'): 'Yes',
       ('N', 'n', 'no', 'nah', 'NO', 'NAH', 'No Data'): 'No'}

repl = {i: v for k, v in dct.items() for i in k}
df_update[column_name] = df_update[clone_col].replace(repl)
```

---

```
0     No
1    Yes
2     No
3    Yes
```